# Deriving four equally-sized bins for student papers in R

Tags: r, algorithm

I regularly teach a class with approximately 160 students in it.  I need to return graded papers back to the students as efficiently as possible.  I split up the papers into a set of four approximately even-sized bins.  I typically use the four corners of the room to do this; one bin per corner to reduce traffic problems and therefore get the papers back rapidly.

The problem is knowing how to split the bins as equivalently as possible.  This varies a bit because the distribution of the first letter of the last names is 1), not uniform throughout the alphabet, and 2), the empirical distribution changes, slightly, from semester-to-semester.  A set of bins for one semester might be A-D, E-H, I-K, and L-Z, but the start and end points could change (except, of course, for A in the first bin and Z in the last bin) each semester.  Note that the bin A-D, for example, would include students with the first letter of their last names for "A", "B", "C", and "D".  Moving the letters out-of-sequence can't be allowed.

Does someone have an idea on how to use R (I use R for everything else in class and the student data is in R) to generate the most efficient (i.e., approximately equally-sized) start and end points of each of the four bins each semester?

I thought perhaps that using "expand.grid" might help to generate all possible combinations of bins and recursively work backwards by eliminating incorrect bins.  I thought about a strictly algorithmic approach with a set of nested loops that not only builds the various bin combinations but also checks the bin sizes with cumulative sums too.  I also thought this might be a variant of a Integer Programming/Constraint Logic/knapsack program for an LP solver.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Here's a vector of 8-letter nonsense names we can use for test data: `set.seed(123); who = apply(matrix(sample(letters,160*8,TRUE),ncol=8),1,paste0,sep="",collapse="")`

Comment: Is it completely necessary to have a bin's boundaries defined by only the first letters? For example, you could divide up the class by four and have each bin defined by the students' names that occupy the boundaries. And if everyone's last name is Smith, could you just assign each student a bin that they'll go to every time?

Answer (score 3):

Using this bunch of odd-named students:

```
set.seed(123); who = apply(matrix(sample(letters,160*8,TRUE),ncol=8),1,paste0,sep‌​="",collapse="")
```

First get the first letters of their names:

```
fl = substr(who,1,1)
```

The cumulative sum of the table of first letters:

```
cs = cumsum(table(fl))
```

looks like this:

```
> cs
  a   b   c   d   e   f   g   h   i   j   k   l   m   n   o   p   q   r   s   t 
  3   8  15  25  29  35  44  48  56  62  71  79  86  89  95 100 105 114 118 123 
  u   v   w   x   y   z 
130 135 138 148 155 160
```

Which tells us that the 40th student in alphabetical order starts with F, the 80th with L, the 120th with S. We can get those like this:

```
> names(tail(which(cs <40) ,1))
[1] "f"
> names(tail(which(cs <80) ,1))
[1] "l"
> names(tail(which(cs <120) ,1))
[1] "s"
```

So our report piles are labelled A-F, G-L, M-S, and T-Z

Converting letters to numbers and cutting the first letter vector into ranges defined by those intervals (again converted to letter numbers) gives us the number of student running to each corner:

```
> table(cut(as.numeric(factor(fl)),c(0,7,12,19,27)))

  (0,7]  (7,12] (12,19] (19,27] 
     44      35      39      42
```

Comment: This looks nice.  Are the cut points fully inclusive, or are some letters inadvertently distributed across more than one bin?

Comment: The letters printed by the `names(tail....` lines, plus "z", are the right inclusive limits of the categories. All names A-F are group 1, all G-L are group 2, all M-S are group 3, all T-Z are group 4. The finds the 40th (80th, 120th) student in alphabetical, and decides that their first letter is the cutoff letter. That might include more than 40 students.

Comment: Note this fails if, for example there are 42 students starting with "A". Because then the first letter of the second group will also be A... As long as you don't have more than 40 students in a letter I don't think anything like this can happen.

Comment: Spacedman, thanks for your insight, code, and documentaton.  I put it into working production today.  Again, thanks.